# open front camera using kivy python on android

Tags: python, android, kivy, front-camera

I want open front android camera using kivy .in kivy document written index =0 is for back camera and index=1 is for front camera .when I use index=0 and covert code by buildozer to apk it is ok and app not crashed but when I change index=1 and convert it by buildozer app will be crashed .
can someone help me please ?